# Django: saerializer.save() not passing argument from url parameter with ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "Comment.blog" must be a "Blog" instance

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I want to save comments with a blog as ForeignKey. I am trying to get the blog slug through the url parameter. Then, I,m getting the blog id through the slug by running a query and passing it to the `serializer.save()` method to save the comment with this blog id.

As far as I know, the Comment should save with the blog id as it is mentioned in the `serializer.save(..)` method. But why is it not even recognising that I'm passsing the blog id also?

When I'm trying it in Postman it's showing this:

```
Request body:
{
    "comment_text": "Hello world!"
}

Response:
{
    "blog": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey('Blog', related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customuser = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    comment_text = models.TextField()
```

My urlpattern:

```
path('<str:slug>/comments/', CommentListView.as_view(), name='comments'),
```

My view:

```
class CommentListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        return Comment.objects.all().filter(blog__slug = slug)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        blog_pk = Blog.objects.get(slug = self.kwargs['slug']).pk
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save(customuser=self.request.user, blog=blog_pk)      // Save with current user and blog
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found where I was going wrong. There are two issues:

1. I need to make the `blog` field read-only as I wan't it to auto-populate. In the serializer, I added this line:

```
class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ('blog', 'customuser', 'comment_text', 'created_on', 'updated_on', 'deleted', 'likes',)
    read_only_fields = ('blog',)
```

2. Next issue was that I had to pass the blog to the `Comment` serializer as an instance, i.e., in simple words, an entire row from the `Blog` model filtered by any of its field, which in my case is the slug.

To solve this I had to use `get_object_or_404` and changed my `create()` method like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class CommentSerializer(serializers.ListCreateAPIView):
    ...
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        blog_pk = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save(blog=blog_pk, customuser=self.request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```